# Полчему find работает только когда содержимое обернуто в блок?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне приходит от сервера шаблонизированый html список новостей, я хочу как-то работать с ним, но выходит плохо

Для примера:

```
$('<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>').find('div:last').text();
```

Этот код выдаст пустую строку

Но если все обернуть ещё в чего-то, то все работает:

```
$('<div><div>test1</div><div>test2</div></div>').find('div:last').text();
```

Мне очень не нравится такой костыль, есть ли нормальное решение?

Comment: что в первом, что во втором случае написан бред... зачем писать `'<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>'` или `<div><div>test1</div><div>test2</div></div>` ? Работать надо с **селекторами**

Comment: Привидите действительную разметку, а не пример div'ов. Не верю, что у вас классов никаких нету... Если нету — тогда пора начать думать компонентами (блоками). БЭМ в помощь (тема именно именование классов). Вам будет проще узлы элементов выбирать и код поддерживать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ищет потомков внутри каждого элемента в текущем наборе.

В первом случае в наборе два `div` без потомков, поэтому `.find()` ничего не находит.

Во втором случае `div` с двумя потомками.

То, что вам нужно называется [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) и работает так:

```
$('<div>test1</div><div>test2</div>').filter(':last').text();
```

Comment: А если я хочу пройтись `each` по всем `div.className` внутри?